# Do my up votes count once I have enough reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting

I have a reputation of 11 at the moment, but I have found a couple a very useful questions and answers, things I would like to up vote. If I do so now, it does not show up, but I believe it is stored. Does the person who posted the question/answer received reputation once my reputation is high enough for an up vote to count? Or, do I need to remember where I placed these votes and revisit them once my reputation is high enough and vote again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither.

Anonymous feedback (positive and negative) is in a different bin and affects things like placement on the home page, search results, etc.. but it doesn't grant direct reputation.

You can look at this [help section](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) to see how reputation works in specific.

Comment: Thanks. I did read that page, and maybe I'm over looking it, but I could find anything about votes given before my reputation is high enough. And when you say "neither" does that mean that I can not go back and vote again? Is there any way for the write to gain the reputation from my vote?

Comment: @boredrandom The first link in that document covers reputation generally. You're not voting up with 10 rep - it's the same as anonymous feedback. You don't get a "vote" until you have 15 rep. You have feedback that's positive or negative - that's all.

Comment: Thank you. That's the part I wasn't understanding, that it's equivalent to being anonymous, that it's not even a vote.